# Gaussian NB vs LDA in scikit learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, lda, naivebayes

From my understanding, if we only have one feature, then Gaussian NB (naive bayes classification) and LDA (Linear Discriminant Analysis) should give the same result.

But I didn't succeed with scikit learn.

First I generate some toy data

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=20, centers=2, n_features=1,
                  random_state=0)
```

Then I create a NB model with Gaussian distribution

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
gnb = GaussianNB()
gnb.fit(X, y)
```

Then a LDA model

```
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
lda = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()
lda.fit(X, y)
```

Now it is possible to plot the results.

```
plt.scatter(X,y)
X_test = np.linspace(-1, 8, 300).reshape(-1,1)

plt.plot(X_test, gnb.predict_proba(X_test.reshape(-1,1))[:,1],color="black")
plt.plot(X_test, lda.predict_proba(X_test.reshape(-1,1))[:,1],color="green")

plt.ylabel('y')
plt.xlabel('X')

plt.axhline(.5, color='.5')
plt.show()
```

But I got the following plot

[image]

Maybe I didn't these algorithms. Could you explain why the differences?

Answer (score 3):

The main high-level difference between GNB, LDA and QDA when there are two classes `C1` and `C2` is as follows:

GNB : assumes covariance of `X` under classes `C1` and `C2` are different, but the off-diagonal elements are `0`.

QDA : assumes covariance of `X` under classes `C1` and `C2` are different, and the off-diagonal elements are not equal to `0`.

LDA : assumes covariance of `X` under classes `C1` and `C2` are same, and the off-diagonal elements are not equal to `0`.

All three assume that the means of `X` under `C1` and `C2` are different.

When `X` is only 1 variable, GNB should default to be the same as QDA as both assume that the variance of `X` under the two classes are different, while LDA would be generally different as it assumes variance of `X` under the two classes are the same (unless by coincidence the variances of the two classes are equal).

In your example, the variance of `X` when `y = 1` and `y = 0` are `1.045` and `0.950` respectively (which is what GNB will assume for two classes), while the variance of `X` is `1.678` (which is what LDA will assume for both the classes). Hence, their solutions will be slightly different.

Unfortunately, though, even if I replace LDA with Sklearn's QDA implementation, I get different curves. I suspect it could be due to implementation differences in Sklearn (e.g. rounding off issues, or perhaps `n` vs `n-1` in calculation of variances, etc.).